# If $f''(x)=0$ but is not an inflection point, what is it called?

Tags: calculus, terminology

If the second derivative of a function $f(x)$ equals zero at point $x_0$ ( $f''(x_0)=0$ ), the point is an inflection point if the concavity changes. [Here's an example of an inflection point.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html)

**If the concavity does *not* change, what is the point called?** Does it have any specific name?

Comment: A critical point of the derivative. (No, it doesn't have any specific name).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay, thanks!

Comment: @Arturo: Perhaps you should make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called an undulation point.
(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point.)

Answer (score 2):

(Made into an answer so the question doesn't go without one).

The point does not have any specific name that denotes the fact that it is not a point of inflection. Of course, it is still a critical point of the derivative (one which is not a local extreme of the derivative).

So, no, it does not have a specific name.