# When is $f''(x)$ undefined but $x$ not an inflection point of $f$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, optimization

This is supposed to be for bullet 5.2 in this question: [A rigorous yet intuitive summary of inflection and critical points for beginning calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122373/a-rigorous-yet-intuitive-summary-of-inflection-and-critical-points-for-beginning)

- There are examples for undulation points, where $f: A \to B, A,B \subseteq \mathbb R, f''(x)=0$ but $(x,f(x))$ is not an inflection point of $f$ like $f(t) = \frac{t^4}{12},f''(t)=t^2$ ([If $f''(x)=0$ but is not an inflection point, what is it called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74665/if-fx-0-but-is-not-an-inflection-point-what-is-it-called?rq=1))
- There are examples where $f''(x)$ is undefined but $(x,f(x))$ is an inflection point like $f'(t)=|t|$ ([An inflection point where the second derivative doesn't exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402459/an-inflection-point-where-the-second-derivative-doesnt-exist?rq=1))

**I'm missing something very obvious, but what's an example where $f''(x)$ is undefined, but $(x,f(x))$ is not an inflection point of $f$?**

---

**After some thought, I have come up with some examples. Are these correct?**

*First example*: This example is one where $f$ is defined but not continuous at $x$.

- $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(t)=\text{sign}(t), x=0$. $f'(0)$ is undefined and thus so is $f''(0)$. However $f''(t)=0$ for $t \ne 0$.
- **In case someone asks further** 'Okay, what if we assumed $f$ is continuous? Then $x$ would have to be an inflection point right?', then we proceed:

*Second example:* This example is one where $f$ is continuous but not differentiable at $x$.

- A sharp turn like $g(t)=|t|$ but always increasing at an increasing rate but at different rates $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(t)= t 1_{t \le 0} + 3t 1_{t \ge 0}$. This gives us $f': \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R, f'(t) = \text{sign}(t)+2$. $f'(0)$ is undefined and thus so is $f''(0)$. However $f''(t)>0$ for $t \ne 0$.
- **In case someone asks further** 'Okay, what if we assumed $f$ is differentiable? Then $x$ would have to be an inflection point right?', then we proceed:

*Third example*: This example is one where $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

- $f': \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f'(t)= t 1_{t \le 0} + 3t 1_{t \ge 0}$.

Comment: Case 3 seems like the best answer here, since $f’’(0)$ isn’t defined in the first two cases. I would consider case 3 a good answer to this.

Comment: @DavidM. $f''(0)$ is supposed to be undefined in all cases. What do you mean?

Comment: Oops I completely misread. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DavidM. Edited: This is supposed to be for bullet 5.2 in this question: [A rigorous yet intuitive summary of inflection and critical points for beginning calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122373/a-rigorous-yet-intuitive-summary-of-inflection-and-critical-points-for-beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t tell what you're asking, so I’ll answer the question in the title. Or, more precisely, I’ll give an example of an $f$, differentiable on the whole real line, with the property you describe in the title. I can’t tell what you’re doing by listing all those cases.

Take $f$ to be $x^2$ when $x$ is negative and $x^4$ when $x$ is non-negative.

Then $f’’(0)$ is undefined, and moreover $f$ does not have an inflection point at the origin.

Comment: Thanks! I was giving several answers with different conditions. One might say after the first answer $f(t) = sign(t)$, something like 'Okay, what if we assumed $f$ is continuous? Then $x$ would have to be an inflection point right?' Then comes the second answer. Does that clarify things?

Comment: So what is your question???

Comment: The first question is give an example. If a user gives an answer of a non-continuous function, the next question is give an example of continuous. If a user gives an answer of a non-differentiable function, the next question is give an example of a differentiable function, which you did. Thanks! (I will still edit my post to clarify)

Comment: No, you aren’t understanding. What is **your** question? It seems like you aren’t asking a question at all.

Comment: Okay I edited my question now. Anyway, thanks!